# How to stop and start relisten for client socket connection in C#

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I am working on an ATM project (tcp/ip, C#). I have to click the start button in server application to start listening client. OInce client sends sign on request (connect), connection between server and client is established (up to this part I am done).

When sign of request comes from the client, I have to disconnect the connection and start listen for client again. The code for listening client is as below.

```
public bool startlisten() 
{
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4000];

        try
        {
            //Creates one SocketPermission object for access restrictions
            permission = new SocketPermission(
                 NetworkAccess.Accept,     // Allowed to accept connections 
                 TransportType.Tcp,        // Defines transport types 
                 "",                       // The IP addresses of local host 
                 SocketPermission.AllPorts // Specifies all ports 
            );

            // Listening Socket object 
            sListener = null;

            //Ensures the code to have permission to access a Socket 
            permission.Demand();

            // Resolves a host name to an IPHostEntry instance 
            IPHostEntry ipHost = Dns.GetHostEntry("");

            int portnumber = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("port"));

            // Creates a network endpoint 
            ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, portnumber);

            // Create one Socket object to listen the incoming connection 
            sListener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            // Associates a Socket with a local endpoint 
            sListener.Bind(ipEndPoint);


            // Places a Socket in a listening state and specifies the maximum 
            // Length of the pending connections queue 
            sListener.Listen(10);

            //Begins an asynchronous operation to accept an attempt 
            AsyncCallback aCallback = new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback);
            sListener.BeginAccept(aCallback, sListener);


        }
        catch (Exception exc) {
            return true;
        }

        return true;
}
```

Please guide me how to disconnect from client socket and start listening again.

i have tried

```
//handler.Disconnect(false);                
           //handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
           //handler.Close();
```

sListener and handler are the Socket object.while accepting (acceptconnection) listener is copied to handler.

Comment: The socket is listening whenever a `.BeginAccept` call is pending. This is irrespective of how many clients are actually connected. The idea is that you bind the listen socket once, then call `.BeginAccept` in a loop (and never dispose of the socket until your program terminates). The sockets that are the result of `.EndAccept` are your client connections, and you can do with those as you please.

Comment: same thing i am doing in the line  AsyncCallback aCallback = new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback);
            sListener.BeginAccept(aCallback, sListener);

Comment: You only call it once in this method, and you create a new listen socket every time you call this method. You should create the listen socket *once*, keep it around, and call `.BeginAccept` on that one socket, not create a new one every time. Note that what you do with client sockets (`handler`) has no influence at all on what happens to the listen socket.

Comment: so you are telling in AcceptCallback function i need to call the AcceptCallback() again as loop?

Comment: Yes, you can call `.BeginAccept` from the handler; if you do that no loop is necessary (it is effectively a recursive loop). Take care that you can have multiple clients connected in parallel with this setup. If that's not desirable for some reason, you should probably use `.Listen(1)` (to ensure only one connection request can be pending) and not call `.BeginAccept` until you're done with that client, or else actively reject and close connections as soon as they're made.

Comment: still getting exeption Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted,also i need only one client need to be connected

Comment: Then you're either still calling `.Bind()` more than once, or some other process (possibly another instance of your own) has already claimed the port you're trying to bind to. As the error message says, only one customer per port.